# Multilevel jQuery menu plugin, accessing and setting up options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found a n ice looking multi level plugin which I use on my website, here is link to the plugin: [enter link description here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/)

Here is the code of the plugin :

```
;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

'use strict';

// global
var Modernizr = window.Modernizr, $body = $( 'body' );

$.DLMenu = function( options, element ) {
    this.$el = $( element );
    this._init( options );
};

// the options
$.DLMenu.defaults = {
    // classes for the animation effects
    animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-1', classout : 'dl-animate-out-1' },
    // callback: click a link that has a sub menu
    // el is the link element (li); name is the level name
    onLevelClick : function( el, name ) { return false; },
    // callback: click a link that does not have a sub menu
    // el is the link element (li); ev is the event obj
    onLinkClick : function( el, ev ) { return false; }
};

$.DLMenu.prototype = {
    _init : function( options ) {
        console.log("init");
        // options
        this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.DLMenu.defaults, options );
        // cache some elements and initialize some variables
        this._config();

        var animEndEventNames = {
                'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
                'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
                'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
                'animation' : 'animationend'
            },
            transEndEventNames = {
                'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
                'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
                'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
                'transition' : 'transitionend'
            };
        // animation end event name
        this.animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ] + '.dlmenu';
        // transition end event name
        this.transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ] + '.dlmenu',
        // support for css animations and css transitions
        this.supportAnimations = Modernizr.cssanimations,
        this.supportTransitions = Modernizr.csstransitions;

        this._initEvents();

    },
    _config : function() {
        this.open = false;
        this.$trigger = this.$el.children( '.dl-trigger' );
        this.$menu = this.$el.children( 'ul.dl-menu' );
        this.$menuitems = this.$menu.find( 'li:not(.dl-back)' );
        this.$el.find( 'ul.dl-submenu' ).prepend( '<li class="dl-back"><a href="#">back</a></li>' );
        this.$back = this.$menu.find( 'li.dl-back' );
    },
    _initEvents : function() {

        var self = this;

        this.$trigger.on( 'click.dlmenu', function() {

            if( self.open ) {
                self._closeMenu();
            } 
            else {
                self._openMenu();
            }
            return false;

        } );

        this.$menuitems.on( 'click.dlmenu', function( event ) {

            event.stopPropagation();

            var $item = $(this),
                $submenu = $item.children( 'ul.dl-submenu' );

            if( $submenu.length > 0 ) {

                var $flyin = $submenu.clone().css( 'opacity', 0 ).insertAfter( self.$menu ),
                    onAnimationEndFn = function() {
                        self.$menu.off( self.animEndEventName ).removeClass( self.options.animationClasses.classout ).addClass( 'dl-subview' );
                        $item.addClass( 'dl-subviewopen' ).parents( '.dl-subviewopen:first' ).removeClass( 'dl-subviewopen' ).addClass( 'dl-subview' );
                        $flyin.remove();
                    };

                setTimeout( function() {
                    $flyin.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classin );
                    self.$menu.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classout );
                    if( self.supportAnimations ) {
                        self.$menu.on( self.animEndEventName, onAnimationEndFn );
                    }
                    else {
                        onAnimationEndFn.call();
                    }

                    self.options.onLevelClick( $item, $item.children( 'a:first' ).text() );
                } );

                return false;

            }
            else {
                self.options.onLinkClick( $item, event );
            }

        } );

        this.$back.on( 'click.dlmenu', function( event ) {

            var $this = $( this ),
                $submenu = $this.parents( 'ul.dl-submenu:first' ),
                $item = $submenu.parent(),

                $flyin = $submenu.clone().insertAfter( self.$menu );

            var onAnimationEndFn = function() {
                self.$menu.off( self.animEndEventName ).removeClass( self.options.animationClasses.classin );
                $flyin.remove();
            };

            setTimeout( function() {
                $flyin.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classout );
                self.$menu.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classin );
                if( self.supportAnimations ) {
                    self.$menu.on( self.animEndEventName, onAnimationEndFn );
                }
                else {
                    onAnimationEndFn.call();
                }

                $item.removeClass( 'dl-subviewopen' );

                var $subview = $this.parents( '.dl-subview:first' );
                if( $subview.is( 'li' ) ) {
                    $subview.addClass( 'dl-subviewopen' );
                }
                $subview.removeClass( 'dl-subview' );
            } );

            return false;

        } );

    },
    closeMenu : function() {
        if( this.open ) {
            this._closeMenu();
        }
    },
    _closeMenu : function() {
        var self = this,
            onTransitionEndFn = function() {
                self.$menu.off( self.transEndEventName );
                self._resetMenu();
            };

        this.$menu.removeClass( 'dl-menuopen' );
        this.$menu.addClass( 'dl-menu-toggle' );
        this.$trigger.removeClass( 'dl-active' );

        if( this.supportTransitions ) {
            this.$menu.on( this.transEndEventName, onTransitionEndFn );
        }
        else {
            onTransitionEndFn.call();
        }

        this.open = false;
    },
    openMenu : function() {
        if( !this.open ) {
            this._openMenu();
        }
    },
    _openMenu : function() {
        var self = this;
        // clicking somewhere else makes the menu close
        $body.off( 'click' ).on( 'click.dlmenu', function() {
            self._closeMenu() ;
        } );
        this.$menu.addClass( 'dl-menuopen dl-menu-toggle' ).on( this.transEndEventName, function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( 'dl-menu-toggle' );
        } );
        this.$trigger.addClass( 'dl-active' );
        this.open = true;
    },
    // resets the menu to its original state (first level of options)
    _resetMenu : function() {
        this.$menu.removeClass( 'dl-subview' );
        this.$menuitems.removeClass( 'dl-subview dl-subviewopen' );
    }
};

var logError = function( message ) {
    if ( window.console ) {
        window.console.error( message );
    }
};

$.fn.dlmenu = function( options ) {
    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
        this.each(function() {
            var instance = $.data( this, 'dlmenu' );
            if ( !instance ) {
                logError( "cannot call methods on dlmenu prior to initialization; " +
                "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                return;
            }
            if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
                logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for dlmenu instance" );
                return;
            }
            instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
        });
    } 
    else {
        this.each(function() {  
            var instance = $.data( this, 'dlmenu' );
            if ( instance ) {
                instance._init();
            }
            else {
                instance = $.data( this, 'dlmenu', new $.DLMenu( options, this ) );
            }
        });
    }
    return this;
};

} )( jQuery, window );
```

From what I see, when a click is made, it prevents propagation of the event so the sub menu doesn't reload.
I also see that in the options there is "onLinkClick" but no method to call, so I guess that if I want to handle clicks on the menu, I need to use this option.

I have tried the following to set up the onLinkClick option :

```
$( '#dl-menu-' + panel ).dlmenu({ classin : 'dl-animate-in-1', classout : 'dl-animate-out-1' }, function( el, name ) { return false; }, function( el, ev ) {console.log("test");} );
```

Basically I have copied the default options and just added a console log for the onLinkClick option.

The menu initialize and works well, but nothing appears in the console when I click on the menu.
I'm not used at all at the object/plugin style of coding and I just tried to guess but obviously I was wrong, but can't find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You pass 3 arguments to the function `(obj, fn1, fn2)` that accepts only one argument - options object. If you will call `$().dlmenu({onLinkClick : function( el, ev ) { console.log("test"); })` and you will see the output.

P.S. Options what you pass now ({classin: ..., classout: ...}) are incorrect and you use plugin with default value. Look into `defaults` structure in the source or in the demos in the project's repository.

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm. There's just a } missing in the end of your code but otherwise it's perfect. Now I understand how to use it.
Please post it as answer so you can get the rep for it.
One little question, when I pass options as an obj, it should be within {} and I should always state the option name like : option1: xxxx, option2: xxxxx ... ?

Comment: It's a very common implementation that jQuery objects accepts JavaScript objects as options. `{}` it's just JavaScript object, you can read about objects here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp . Hope it will help you to understand better how it works.

Comment: thanks a lot! I understood it was quite common that's why I want to understand it^^